# Certificate error in docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm behind a corporate firewall and have installed Docker on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server. Following instructions at http://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/.

Things seemed to be OK:-

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

... but I can't pull and run any images. Example:-

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

gives:

> Error while pulling image: Get
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images:
>   x509: certificate is valid for FG3K6C3A15800002, not index.docker.io

Have spent ages searching around - I don't understand what the issue is - I've set http_proxy and https_proxy env vars but not sure what to try next. The docs don't mention any certificate requirements.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: seems a bug in golang, refer to this discussion - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10863

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the proxy. If you are using a proxy to access the internet, you have to change the file **/etc/default/docker** and put your proxy on it.

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy_ip:proxy_port"
export https_proxy="http://proxy_ip:proxy_port"
```

After do it, restart the service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

It works to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Pravins I have the same issue, with my docker 1.11.2 It seems is not taken proxy settings from /etc/default/docker and from env neighter.

So what I did was what it says here

http://docs.master.dockerproject.org/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy

Many Linux distributions use systemd to start the Docker daemon. 
You need check if the docker.service uses an EnvironmentFile, and/or You can customize the Docker daemon options using override files as explained in the HTTP Proxy example below.

Comment: dead links are not that helpful